# Is there a prefabricated magnifying glass cursor for SWT somewhere available?

Tags: java, swt, lazy-evaluation, mouse-cursor

I would like to use a "magnifying glass" (with + and -) cursor in my SWT application. I'm aware [that it is pretty easy to create a cursor for oneself](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html), I just don't want to invest the time right now. Has anyone a link, or a codesnippet with a "zoom in" and "zoom out" cursor which I could use?